# Need to Click Connect Multiple Times in Order to Connect Bluetooth 20.04

Tags: wireless, sound, bluetooth, 20.04, headphones

I am able to successfully pair and connect to Bluetooth devices, but when I connect my headphones to my phone and then attempt to reconnect back to my computer, it initially fails. This is the switch I press:

[image: Bluetooth connection screen]

When I press it, shows a loading symbol, and resets back to the off state. I need to press it multiple times in order to connect to the device.

It works immediately if I use `bluetoothctl` to connect, but that's a bit of a hassle to do. Is there a way that I can fix this behavior?

I am using stock Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: For reference, this is a known issue and you can follow it up here : https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/issues/820